# How to calculate lasst time app is active and check if time exceeds then display login screen

Tags: ios

How to calculate the last time app is active

Comment: If you want to know about four parameter than why you put this code?

Comment: It is already given here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain

Comment: @CRDave please look at the above implementation.Actually I want to implement timer in background thread not in main thread.Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using timers and last touch object